# R order() method on multiple columns gives error "argument lengths differ"

Tags: r

### Examples

```
c1 <- c(1,1,2,2)
c2 <- c(1,2,2,1)
c3 <- as.Date(c("2010-1-1", "2011-1-1", "2013-1-1", "2012-1-1"))

order(c3, decreasing = c(FALSE), method="radix")  # works
order(c1, c2, decreasing = c(TRUE, FALSE), method="radix")  # works
order(c1, c3, decreasing = c(TRUE, FALSE), method="radix")  # fails
```

Why does the last example fail?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Arguably Date and POSIXct vectors should be capable of sorting but the help page says the arguments to order should be "a sequence of numeric, complex, character or logical vectors".

Comment: traceback looks odd `order(c(1, 1, 2, 2), c(14610, 14975, 15706, 15340), na.last = TRUE, 
    decreasing1 = TRUE, decreasing2 = FALSE, method = "radix") `

Comment: @42- good point.  I guess this is more of a feature request than a bug.  Should I delete this question?

Comment: date vector is converted to integer with `as.vector(xtfrm(x))` so that shouldnt matter?

Comment: I'm guessing that the authors didn't want to accidentally sort factor vectors. On the other hand they allow factors when the method is 'missing'. @Ben; I'd leave it in. Seems like an "infelicity" even if "bug" would annoy the higher-ups. It's hard to imagine that allowing Dates and POSIXct objects to be ordered would break any existing code.

Comment: I think this line in order `return(do.call("order", c(z, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, 
                method = method)))` should be `return(do.call("order", c(z, na.last = na.last, decreasing = list(decreasing), 
                method = method)))` perhaps

Comment: I second @rawr in that the problem is due to this code. The suggested correction also seems to work

Comment: Don't know if it works, but I tried to make R-people notice this. Until it is fixed, this works:

    order(c1, as.numeric(c3), decreasing = c(TRUE, FALSE), method="radix")

Comment: @KarlNordström thanks - it seems [this has been fixed in R 3.6.0](https://cran.r-project.org/)

Comment: @Ben, thanks for letting me know!